# Error piping before output

Tags: shell, io-redirection, fish

Let’s you have a group of commands, and some give error as follows:

```
 begin;
     echo “Starting Test";
     ls;
     bad_command -xyz;
 end
```

If you don’t redirect the output or error the results is as expected i.e.

```
Starting Test
foo.txt
someotherfile.png
someDir
Unknown command: ‘bad_command’
```

However, is I pipe the whole block to TextEdit by changing last line to `end 2&>1 | open -f -a TextEdit` the error comes first in the file, and the order is messed up. This also happens when piping to other commands. Why does that happen, and how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this problem because pipes will buffer `stdout` but not `stderr`, and therefore you are getting `stderr` output first. The only way to solve this is to not use pipes, and instead redirect your output to a temporary file. Then, work with that file for what you need to do.